# cscript.exe launched by inno setup installer says cannot find file while it is right there

Tags: inno-setup, wsh

In my Inno setup script, I have this line:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\my.vbs"; DestDir: "C:\folder"; Flags: ignoreversion
[Run]
Filename: "cscript.exe C:\folder\my.vbs"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,my}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser
```

but when the the installation is finished, it pop up an error saying:
Unable to execute file:
cscript.exe C:\folder\my.vbs 
Create process failed; code 2.
the system cannot find the file specified.

When I go to C:\folder, the my.vbs is right there, why would it say it can't find the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Filename` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=Filename), as the name says, is a path to a (executable) file to execute. What in your case is `cscript.exe`.

The rest are parameters of that executable, which go to the [`Parameters` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=Parameters).

```
[Run]
Filename: "cscript.exe"; Parameters: "C:\folder\my.vbs"; \
    Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,my}"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser
```